# Defining type of property when unpacking an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am unpacking an object into a few variables, and I want to define the type of a property that unpacks the remaining properties from an object.

For example:

```js
interface FooBar { name: string }

const {a, b, ...c} = d;
```

I need to declare the type for `c` as `FooBar`.

I've tried pre-declaring the variable:

```js
let c: FooBar;
let {a, b, ...c} = d;
```

Also tried type syntax:

```js
let {a, b, ...c:FooBar} = d;
```

I've tried cast `d` to the type, but get errors that `a` and `b` are not part of the type.

```js
let {a, b, ...c} = d as FooBar;
```

I tried a custom type but get errors:

```js
let {a, b, ...c} = d as {a:any, b:any, c:FooBar};
```

Is there a way to define the types when you unpack an object with TypeScript?

**Updated:**

Here is a better coding example that explains the different types involved:

```js
interface FooBar {
   name: string
}

interface Other {
   a: number;
   b: number;
   name: string;
}

function convert(d: Other) {
   const {a, b, ...c} = d;
   c.name;
   // ^^^ -- WebStorm does not match "name" as a property of FooBar.
   //        It matches to ALL interfaces that have any property called "name". 
}
```

The problem above is that I can not *refactor* the interface `FooBar`, because WebStorm does not explicitly match `c` as implementing that interface. It sees it as matching *all* types that have a `name` property.

So I want to define `c` to be of type `FooBar`.

Comment: Hmm, why would `let {a, b, ...c} = d as FooBar;` work given that `interface Foobar` indeed _doesn't_ have a,b, and c as props?

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on your update you can do this.

```js
interface FooBar {
   name: string
}

interface Other extends FooBar {
   a: number;
   b: number;
}

function convert(d: Other) {
   const {a, b, ...c} = d;
   c.name;
   // ^^^ -- WebStorm will now match "name" as a property of FooBar.
}
```